# Not owner and too little free space problem

Tags: permissions, disk-usage

I am new to Ubuntu. I have just installed it on my computer and it says that I'm not the owner though there is only one account besides guest.

Also, I previously used Windows 8 and deleted it and all other files on my hard drive with DBAN. Although it says that only 4.4 GB of memory is used but the difference between disk size and free space is more than 30 GB. Why is that? Is that from my previous OS and files?

Comment: What's the exact error message Ubuntu is showing about ownership? About the space, "memory" usually means RAM, perhaps you meant "is is showing 4.4 GB of disk space free while it should be more than 30 GB"?

Answer (score 0):

If you only deleted and did not format your hdd before you installed ubuntu or if you chose to install Ubuntu alongside windows OS..Your old files will still be there . Try boot Ubuntu from live CD or usb and format the hdd with Gparted, then install Ubuntu

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) The OP has stated he/she/it already deleted everything with [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/)...  Please edit or delete your answer...